# border-radius doesn't work during transition

Tags: css, animation, masking

I'm using a masking element to clip an image and then scaling that image on hover.

I can't figure out why the border-radius seems to stop existing on the masking element during transition.

http://codepen.io/corysimmons/pen/rOvdXX?editors=110

```
<div class="mask">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/505/505">
</div>

.mask
  overflow: hidden
  width: 300px
  height: 300px
  border-radius: 999em
  img
    transition: all 500ms ease
  &:hover
    img
      transform: scale(1.2)
```

Comment: This looks like a safari problem

Comment: You should use `border-radius: 50%;` for a circle.

Comment: I don't see the issue is this in a certain browser that this occurs?

Comment: @kfreeman04208: That might be because OP seems to have added `z-index: 1` (the fix) into the pen. The code in question doesn't have it. This issue is a known behavior (atleast in Chrome and other webkit powered browsers).

Answer (score 1):

Try and add z-index to the mask placing it on top of the image.

```
.mask
  overflow: hidden
  width: 300px
  height: 300px
  border-radius: 50%
  z-index : 1;
  position : relative;
  img
    transition: all 500ms ease
  &:hover
    img
      transform: scale(1.2)
```